# Notepad++ and Regex to put a bunch of word into [ ], each word in quotation mark and separated by commas

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list, a thousand row like this

> "Categories": "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Fantasy",
>
> "Categories": "Action, Adventure",
>   "Categories": "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Drama,Fantasy, Martial Arts, Mystery, Supernatural", 
>   "Categories": "Action,Adventure, Comedy, Fantasy,Psychological, School Life, Supernatural",

and I'd like to make into this

> "Categories": ["Action", "Adventure", "Comedy", "Fantasy"]
>
> "Categories": ["Action", "Adventure"]
>   "Categories": ["Action", "Adventure", "Comedy", "Drama", "Fantasy", "Mystery", "Supernatural"] 
>   "Categories": ["Action", "Adventure", "Comedy", "Fantasy", "Psychological", "Supernatural"]

I've tried a bunch of regular expression, such as

```
("Categories":) "(\b.*?), (\b.*?), (.*), (.*), (\w+?)",
```

and still stuck, because I am still green at this stuff

please help me to solve this in regex and thank you for the answer

Comment: you can just record a macro and reproduce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two steps:

**step 1:** you replace the string with an array of strings when there is more than one item

```
search: "Categories":\s*\K("[^",]*+[^"]+")
replace: [$1]
```

**step 2:** you replace all the commas in the string

```
search: (\G(?!^)|"Categories":\s*\[")[^",]+?\K\s*,\s*
replace: ", "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

pattern: ("Categories":) ("[^"]*")

substitute with: $1[$2]

bye

Comment: thank you for the answer,
but it not work, it just add [] inside the "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Fantasy",
not ["Action", "Adventure", "Comedy", "Fantasy"]

Comment: With Notepad++ V6.6.9 I obtain:  "Categories":["Action, Adventure, Comedy, Fantasy"],"Categories":["Action, Adventure"],
 "Categories":["Action, Adventure, Comedy, Drama,Fantasy, Martial Arts, Mystery, Supernatural"], "Categories":["Action,Adventure, Comedy, Fantasy,Psychological, School Life, Supernatural"],